# How to create a local table inside a Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a local table inside of a Postgres query that I am currently running. I have tried to create a new table in a join but it just adds a line the result set.

My end goal is to have each input number aline with the output number in each Machine Run. Currently it shows the input on one line and all of its outputs below it.

Is it possible to create a table inside of this query and I can add a Else statement to pull data from the table I created inside of the query?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
SELECT 

"MaterialType"."name",
concat('Run #', "MachineRun"."id")                                            AS "Machine Run",
CASE WHEN "RunMaterial"."is_input" = TRUE THEN "Tag"."uid"
    ELSE NULL END                                                             AS "(Input)",
CASE WHEN "RunMaterial"."is_input" = FALSE THEN "Tag"."uid"
    ELSE NULL END                                                             AS "(Output)",
FROM tenant_tenant "Tenant"
    INNER JOIN core_machinerun "MachineRun"
        ON "Tenant"."id" = "MachineRun"."tenant_id"
    INNER JOIN core_runmaterial "RunMaterial"
        ON "MachineRun"."id" = "RunMaterial"."machine_run_id"
    INNER JOIN core_material "Material"
        ON "RunMaterial"."material_id" = "Material"."id" 
    INNER JOIN core_machine "Machine"
        ON "MachineRun"."machine_id" = "Machine"."id"
    INNER JOIN integrations_tag "Tag"
        ON "Material"."tag_id" = "Tag"."id"
    INNER JOIN core_materialtype "MaterialType"
        ON "Material"."material_type_id" = "MaterialType"."id"
```

Below are the images of my current return and the goal I am looking for.

[image: Current State]

[image: End Goal]

On the left is what I need my results to be, If I change my CASE WHEN for my INPUT column, the result is on the right.

[image]

Comment: Can you please detail a little bit more what you want, and also give some examples?

Comment: I added another image above. I am looking for a result similar to the left in the Excel example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edit answer, you can try to use `MAX` window function to make it as below (`T` is your query in your question.)

```
SELECT MachineRun,MAX(input) OVER(PARTITION BY MachineRun),output
FROM T
```

so it might look like that.

```
SELECT 
    "MaterialType"."name",
    concat('Run #', "MachineRun"."id")                                            AS "Machine Run",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "RunMaterial"."is_input" = TRUE THEN "Tag"."uid"
        ELSE NULL END)  OVER  (PARTITION BY "MachineRun"."id")                    AS "(Input)",
    CASE WHEN "RunMaterial"."is_input" = FALSE THEN "Tag"."uid"
        ELSE NULL END                                                             AS "(Output)"
FROM tenant_tenant "Tenant"
    INNER JOIN core_machinerun "MachineRun"
        ON "Tenant"."id" = "MachineRun"."tenant_id"
    INNER JOIN core_runmaterial "RunMaterial"
        ON "MachineRun"."id" = "RunMaterial"."machine_run_id"
    INNER JOIN core_material "Material"
        ON "RunMaterial"."material_id" = "Material"."id" 
    INNER JOIN core_machine "Machine"
        ON "MachineRun"."machine_id" = "Machine"."id"
    INNER JOIN integrations_tag "Tag"
        ON "Material"."tag_id" = "Tag"."id"
    INNER JOIN core_materialtype "MaterialType"
        ON "Material"."material_type_id" = "MaterialType"."id"
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=df28a447ae277b52b69176fd492db74d)

Comment: Doing this will return the "Output" and "Input" under the "Input" column. I need to copy the "Input" number and display the input and output on the same line. The input and Output in the same table and its either true or false.

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez I am not sure what did you mean you might provide more detail or sample data from your question.

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez if `is_input` is bool type and not null that will only two value in that column one is `true` another is `false`, if you want to combine input and output for input column my answer might be work

Comment: I added a image of my results when I make the change you suggested. Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez I had edited my answer, you can try that.